# Processing custom MenuBar is not displaying

Tags: java, menu, awt, processing

I have created a custom MenuBar in my Processing sketch (using Eclipse as my IDE), but it is not displaying.
Here is a MacOSX MenuBar:

[image: A MenuBar on a Mac]

Below is my code. The project is called `ProcessingTrials` and the class is called `ProcessingSketch` under package `com.kritixilithos.trials`. I am running the program as a Java Application. I have created a `File` Menu and a `Save...` dropdown MenuItem under `File`.

```
//package and imports
package com.kritixilithos.trials;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Menu;
import java.awt.MenuBar;
import java.awt.MenuItem;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import processing.core.*;

import processing.core.*;

public class ProcessingSketch extends PApplet{
    public void settings() {
        //size of Processing sketch
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        double width = screenSize.getWidth();
        double height = screenSize.getHeight();
        size((int)width, (int)height);//"full screen" with menu bar showing
    }

    public void buildMenuBar() {
        //code for menubar
        MenuBar menuBar;
        Menu menu;
        MenuItem menuItem;

        menuBar = new MenuBar();

        menu = new Menu("File");
        menuBar.add(menu);

        menuItem = new MenuItem("Save...");

        menu.add(menuItem);
        menuBar.add(menu);
        menuBar.setName("MenuBar");
        frame.setMenuBar(menuBar);
    }

    public void setup() {
        background(0);
        buildMenuBar();
    }
    //the draw method
    public void draw() {

        text("Hello World!",100,100);
    }
    //main method
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
        System.setProperty("com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name", "something");
        PApplet.main(new String[] {"com.kritixilithos.trials.ProcessingSketch"});
        System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
        System.setProperty("com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name", "something");
    }
}
```

This is the result of the program:

[image: Screenshot of result]

Above (in the top-left corner) , you can see that there is no `File` Menu. I expected there to be a `File` Menu in the `MenuBar`, but there is none.

**My question is this: Did I make a mistake in my program that does not make the Menu appear, or is it simply because Processing `PApplet` does not have support for adding a custom MenuBar?**

Some technical details:

- I am using Java SE version 1.8
- My computer's OS is Mac OS X 10.10.2
- I am using Processing version 3.0.1's `core.jar` in Eclipse

**Note:** There were no errors in the console and the `draw` function was working perfectly.

Any help to resolve this problem (to make the Menu appear in the MenuBar) will be appreciated.

Comment: Is your `draw()` function being triggered properly? Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: @KevinWorkman My `draw` function is working properly and there are no errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I would try putting this as the first line in the main method:

```
System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
```